# graphviz render to gdiplus

Tags: c++, mfc, gdi+, graphviz

I'm taking a look at graphviz (gvc) to embed the creation of some graphs in an MFC app that I am working with.

As far as I can see, it's pretty simple to render to a png file, but I wanted to render it to a gdiplus context without having to write a temporary file to disk to display (which seems to be the only option). Is this possible?

Regards Candag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's possible, if you write your own renderer plug-in. See http://www.graphviz.org/doc/libguide/libguide.pdf . It's already done for X11 (see http://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/output.html#d:xlib) so you can probably work with that as an inspiration, probably 'all' you'd have to do is translate xlib primitives into GDI(+) primitives.

That said, for me it wasn't worth it, I just render to a temporary file and read that in. It's not as nice conceptually but for the user it doesn't make any difference, and it would be a significant amount of work to implement and debug the renderer mentioned above. I suspect that for the use cases where the output of graphviz is good enough, that the optimisation of having a native Gdi renderer isn't worth it...

Comment: I guessed as much, but it's always worth seeing how other people solved the same problem. The only thing that bothers me about this is that you will loose proper zooming, but... I'm not going to implement a renderer myself :)